# A Pentagon AFBCGA is inscribed in a Triangle ∆ABC , what will be it's area?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Consider a $∆ABC$ and a Pentagon $AFBCGA$ as shown below:
[image]
Here all the dotted red lines are perpendicular to a common side $BC$, their lengths are also given with red pen ; also length of $BC$ is given.Now how will we calculate the area of the inscribed Pentagon?

**My thoughts**:
If we could find $BM,MN,NP,PQ,QR \, \& \, RC$;
Then by using area of right triangle and area of trapezium formulas ,we can find the area of the required Pentagon

**My Approach**:
Let $BM=f,MN=e,NP=d,PQ=c,QR=b \, \& \, RC=a$;
then, $$a+b+c+d+e+f=10 $$ 
and by using similar triangle concepts we will get $5$ more independent equations on $a,b,c,d,e \,\& \,f$
i.e, In $∆ABP $ 
$$\frac{5}{8}=\frac{f}{f+e+d} \quad \quad \because ∆DBM \sim ∆ABP$$
and so on...

So, total six variables and six independent equations, hence we might expect an unique solution after solving this set of simultaneous linear equations.

But, Wolfram app is giving it's coefficient matrix determinant as $ 0$.
Hence,they are not all independent
So how to solve this problem?Any help please...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the distances such as $BM$ are not unique, which is why your approach is not working. If you take the simpler problem of finding the area of $ABC$, you can't do it by locating $P$, because $P$ could be anywhere in $BC$; but it's still easy to find the area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to deal with that many variables. Notice $$\frac{\verb/Ar/(ABF)}{\verb/Ar/(ABC)} = \frac{DF}{DC} = 1 - \frac{FC}{DC} = 1 - \frac{FN}{DM} = 1 - \frac45 = \frac15$$
$$\frac{\verb/Ar/(CAG)}{\verb/Ar/(CAB)} = \frac{EG}{EB} = 1  - \frac{GB}{EB} = 1 - \frac{GQ}{ER} = 1 - \frac23 = \frac13$$

We have
$$\begin{align}
\verb/Ar/(AFBCG) 
&= \verb/Ar/(ABC) - \verb/Ar/(ABF) - \verb/Ar/(CAG)\\
&= \left(1 - \frac15 - \frac13\right)\verb/Ar/(ABC)\\
&= \frac7{15} \times \frac{(AP)(BC)}{2}\\ 
&= \frac{56}{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: How $\frac{Ar(∆ABF)}{Ar(∆ABC)} =\frac{DF}{DC}$ ?

Comment: @Suresh Since $\triangle ABF$ and $\triangle ABC$ have a common side $AB$, ratio of their area equals to ratios of  their height which in terms equals to the ratio of the two line segments $DF$ and $DC$.

Comment: But we are not given CD is perpendicular to AB?

Comment: @Sameernilkhan there is no need for $CD$ to be perpendicular to $AB$, Let $F'$ be the perpendicular projection of $F$ on  $AB$ and $C'$ be corr. projection of $C$ on $AB$, the two triangles $DFF'$ and $DCC'$ are similar, so the ratio of height $FF' : CC' = DF : DC$.

Comment: I got it , thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I considered BM=a, MN=b, NP=c, PQ=d, QR=e and RC=f.
Then by the same method as you told I got the following six equations
4b-c-d-e-f=0
5f-3d-3e=0
3a-5b-5c=0
a+b+c+d+e+f=10
2b+2c+2d-3e-3f=0, and
c+d-e-f=0. On solving these six equations we get unique values of all the variables i.e.
a=55/12 , b=13/12 , c=5/3 , d=1/2 , e=7/6 , f=1.

Comment: How you are getting $c+d-e-f=0$ ?

Comment: triangle FNC ~ triangle GQC => FN/GQ = (c+d+e+f)/(e+f) = 4/2 => c+d-e-f=0.

Comment: From which site you have got the values of $a=55/12,b=...$; in Wolfram it is giving no values!! https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=a9536b3eddefb39312a81eeeb828835f&title=Systems%20of%206%20Equations%20Solver&theme=&i0=a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%2Be%2Bf%3D10&i1=4b-c-d-e-f%3D0&i2=5f-3d-3e%3D0&i3=3a-5b-5c%3D0&i4=2b%2B2c%2B2d-3e-3f%3D0&i5=c%2Bd-%20e-f%3D0&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1

Comment: I guess I made some mistake . Will check it once again